# r: group by multiple columns and count

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe, `df`:

```
LeftOrRight SpeedCategory   NumThruLanes
R           25to45          3             
L           45to62          2           
R           Gt62            1
```

I want to group it by SpeedCategory and loop through the other columns to get the frequency of each unique code in each speed category-- something like this:

```
                 25to45 45to62 Gt62
LeftOrRight    L      0      1    0
               R      1      0    1
NumThruLanes   1      0      0    1
               2      0      1    0
               3      1      0    0
```

The closest I have been able to come to is this:

```
for (col in df){
tbl <- table(col, df$SpeedCategory)
print(tbl)
}
```

Which prints out the following (first SpeedCategory, then NumThruLanes):

```
col   25to45 45to62 Gt62
  L        0      1    0
  R        1      0    1

col   25to45 45to62 Gt62
  1        0      0    1
  2        0      1    0
  3        1      0    0
```

I am pretty sure i can accomplish my goal with `aggregate()` or maybe group_by from `dplyr`, but I am new to R and can't figure out the syntax. In `pandas` I would use a `MultiIndex` but I don't know what the R equivalent is so it's difficult to google.

I'd like to try to do everything in one pass, or with a loop, since I have over a dozen columns to get through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tables` package makes it easy to format tables in very specific ways. The syntax takes some getting used to, but for this problem it's pretty straight-forward:

```
exd <- read.table(text = "LeftOrRight SpeedCategory   NumThruLanes
R           25to45          3             
L           45to62          2           
R           Gt62            1", header = TRUE)       

## to get counts by default we need everything to be categorical
exd$SpeedCategory <- factor(exd$SpeedCategory)

library(tables)
tabular(LeftOrRight + NumThruLanes ~ SpeedCategory, data = exd)

##                SpeedCategory            
##                25to45        45to62 Gt62
## LeftOrRight  L 0             1      0   
##              R 1             0      1   
## NumThruLanes 1 0             0      1   
##              2 0             1      0   
##              3 1             0      0
```

If you have a lot of columns to iterate over, you can construct the formula programatically, e.g.,

```
tabular(as.formula(paste(paste(names(exd)[-2], collapse = " + "),
                         names(exd)[2], sep = " ~ ")),
        data = exd)
```

As a bonus there are `html` and `latex` methods, making it easy to mark your table up for inclusion in an article or report.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you! I ended up having to convert all my columns to factors with lapply(df, factor), and it worked great after that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do everything in one pass using `lapply()` instead of a for loop:

```
tab_list <- lapply(df[, -2], function(col) table(col, df$SpeedCategory))
tab_list
## $LeftOrRight
##    
## col 25to45 45to62 Gt62
##   L      0      1    0
##   R      1      0    1
## 
## $NumThruLanes
##    
## col 25to45 45to62 Gt62
##   1      0      0    1
##   2      0      1    0
##   3      1      0    0
```

You can then combine the tables into one using `rbind()` with `do.call()`:

```
do.call(rbind, tab_list)
##   25to45 45to62 Gt62
## L      0      1    0
## R      1      0    1
## 1      0      0    1
## 2      0      1    0
## 3      1      0    0
```

It is possible to get a column in the output table that indicates the column name from the original data frame. To achieve this, you need to `lapply()` over the column names with a somewhat more complicated function:

```
tab_list <- lapply(names(df)[-2], function(col) {
  tab <- table(df[, col], df[, "SpeedCategory"])
  name_col <- c(col, rep("", nrow(tab) - 1))
  mat <- cbind(name_col, rownames(tab), tab)
  as.data.frame(mat)
  })
do.call(rbind, tab_list)
##       name_col V2 25to45 45to62 Gt62
## L  LeftOrRight  L      0      1    0
## R               R      1      0    1
## 1 NumThruLanes  1      0      0    1
## 2               2      0      1    0
## 3               3      1      0    0
```

Comment: This looks promising. Is there a way to maintain the column names for each subdivision of rows (LeftOrRight, NumThruLanes, etc.) in do.call() (other than manually adding a column) such that it looks a little more like my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

With `dcast` from reshape2 package you could do:

```
library("reshape2")

DF=read.table(text="LeftOrRight SpeedCategory   NumThruLanes
R           25to45          3             
L           45to62          2           
R           Gt62            1",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

LR_Stat = dcast(DF,LeftOrRight ~ SpeedCategory,length,fill=0)
LR_Stat
#  LeftOrRight 25to45 45to62 Gt62
#1           L      0      1    0
#2           R      1      0    1

Lanes_Stat = dcast(DF,NumThruLanes ~ SpeedCategory,length,fill=0)
Lanes_Stat
#  NumThruLanes 25to45 45to62 Gt62
#1            1      0      0    1
#2            2      0      1    0
#3            3      1      0    0
```

Note that LR_Stat should have have 1 for range 45to62 in your expected output

Comment: Fixed, thanks! This works, but I have a lot of columns to get through. Is there a way to do this without naming columns explicitly? I tried looping and appending each object to a blank dataframe, but that doesn't seem to work...