# Group by a column and then automatically count over multiple columns starting with the same alphabet

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count, aggregate

I am trying to do a simple `counts` action combined with the `group_by` functionality.

For example, if the `df` is as below:

```
Task   q1  q2
Alpha  1   NA
Beta   NA  NA
Alpha  4   2
Alpha  5   NA
Beta   2   2
Gamma  NA  3
```

I want to have the following output

```
Task   q1   q2
Alpha  3    1 
Beta   1    1 
Gamma  0    1
```

#### Requirement 1:

Overall, I want to count how many times the entries correspond to non-missing values (anything from 0-5 in this example). I am not interested in what the values are, I am only interested in how many times they are reported - corresponding to each of the tasks.

I can do this using the `sqldf` as below:

```
sqldf('SELECT Task, count(q1), count(q2)
FROM df
GROUP BY Task')
```

I can also do this using the `dplyr` package:

```
df %>%  
  group_by(Task) %>% 
  summarise(q1 = sum(!is.na(q1)),
            q2 = sum(!is.na(q2)))
```

But I want to know if there is an automated way of doing this, for example when I have a variable number of measures, sometimes `q1:q3` and sometimes they may be `q1:q10`. Something like `paste0("q", 1:n)`. But I am having difficulty incorporating this into my code.

#### Requirement 2:

Later on, I also want to calculate the percentage of occurrence of each of the measures `q` for each of the tasks `alpha, beta, gamma`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have seen other posts but they have not been useful to me, probably because of my lack of ability in coding using the `dplyr` package. For example,

[r: group by multiple columns and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306629/r-group-by-multiple-columns-and-count),

[How do I get count from multiple columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086816/how-do-i-get-count-from-multiple-columns-in-r)

and

[Count occurance of multiple columns by group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265951/count-occurance-of-multiple-columns-by-group-in-r)

Comment: `sprintf("select Task, %s from df group by Task", toString(sprintf("count(%s)", paste0("q", 1:n))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `across` to apply a function to multiple columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Task) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = ~sum(!is.na(.))))
  #Or if you have other columns in your data 
  #apply the function to only the columns that start with 'q'
  #summarise(across(starts_with('q'), ~sum(!is.na(.))))

#  Task     q1    q2
#  <chr> <int> <int>
#1 Alpha     3     1
#2 Beta      1     1
#3 Gamma     0     1
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Ronak Shah I will run it on my original data and get back to you. Any advice on how we could update it to include percentage instead of counts?

Comment: To get percentage replace `sum` with `mean`.